# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class j$.time.ZoneId:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

I'm having trouble figuring out what proguard/r8 configuration can I use to avoid the error below.

The environment:

- openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
- Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.0-beta03
- Gradle 7.0.2
- app/build.gradle.kts:

```
android { 
  compileSdkPreview = "android-S"
  defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 30
  }
  compileOptions { 
    isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true 
  } 
  buildType{
    getByName("release") {
      isDebuggable = false
      isMinifyEnabled = true
      isShrinkResources = true
  }
}
   
dependencies { 
  coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9") 
}
```

I'm experiecing the following runtime exception.

```
06-09 15:43:42.994 11747 11747 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 15:43:42.994 11747 11747 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 11747
06-09 15:43:42.994 11747 11747 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class j$.time.ZoneId: j$.time.ZoneId j$.time.ZoneId.q(java.lang.String, j$.time.ZoneOffset) failed to verify: j$.time.ZoneId j$.time.ZoneId.q(java.lang.String, j$.time.ZoneOffset): [0x10]  can't resolve returned type 'Reference: j$.time.ZoneId' or 'Unresolved Reference: j$.time.ZoneOffset'
06-09 15:43:42.994 11747 11747 E AndroidRuntime:  j$.time.ZoneId j$.time.ZoneId.r(java.lang.String, int, boolean) failed to verify: j$.time.ZoneId j$.time.ZoneId.r(java.lang.String, int, boolean): [0x3D] unexpected non-exception class Reference: a.b (declaration of 'j$.time.ZoneId' appears in /data/app/~~t4Hx1UMkLP0rmmxs6BLp2A==/com.example.myapp-gaznFp2vMqRsP8uHlL-Rpg==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

Note:

If `-dontobfuscate` is added to the proguard/r8 configuration file, then the runtime error goes away.
Obviously this is not ideal and hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded `desugar_jdk_libs` to 1.1.15 and the issue seems to be gone.

Changelog also indicates changes to error classes:

https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Good to hear. We have updated the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to suggest 1.1.5 as well.